# Drawing a solid sphere with transparency in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, transparency, glut

I want to draw a `glutSolidSphere` with some transparency, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 0); // should be completely invisible
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
glutSolidSphere(3, 5, 5);
glPopMatrix();
```

In my main function, I initialize with the following display mode:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to explicitely setup [alpha blending](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm) . [Another example](http://www.webkinesia.com/online/graphics/notes/blending.php).

> glEnable (GL_BLEND);
>
> glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: This works now if multiple objects overlap. However, if there is a fully transparent object with nothing behind, it renders the object instead of the background color

Comment: void renderScene(void) {
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: http://www.scriptreactor.com/transparency.png <-- the red spheres should be completely transparent.

Comment: okay, had used another blending function accidently. works now. thanks